# Convert Existing Application from using sqlmembership to simplemembership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been scouring the internet trying to find a solution to this problem.  I have altered the role and membership providers to use SimpleMembership, but it is still referencing the old ("aspnet_XXX") tables.  I have found [this solution](http://pretzelsteelersfan.blogspot.com/2012/11/migrating-legacy-apps-to-new.html), but it seems like it is only dealing with the user data and moving it over to the new tables.  Maybe I'm just reading it wrong.  Anyone have any advise on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't gone deep, I would to suggest to convert to new ASP.Net Identity comes with MVC 5.

Microsoft has replaced SimpleMembership with ASP.Net Identity.

[Introducing ASP.NET Identity – A membership system for ASP.NET applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx)

[Forms authentication using ASP.NET Identity & VS 2013 Preview](http://www.novanet.no/blog/olav-nybo/dates/2013/8/forms-authentication-using-aspnet-identity--vs-2013-preview/)